# How to split Column Value under Particular column Name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the Main Value as per below table. Now, I need to keep the each value under particular column name .All the values are space separated. Let say, the Main value is:2 3 6 7.

Now, 2 should goes under the column name 2. 3 Should goes under the column name 3 and same as 6 should goes under the column name 6 and 7 should goes under the column name 7. In excel there have a option name "text to column". Using this function the value can split but it's not goes to it's particular column name.

[image]

Please help , how shall I do that. Thanks in advance.
[I am using "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019"]

Comment: The solution is given by  @MayukhBhattacharya is working for me:  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(" "&B$1&" "," "&$A3&" "),B$1),"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you could do, if you are not using `MS365`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A3," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),
IFERROR(INDEX(x,MATCH(1,N(x=B$1),0)),""))
```

---

And Fill Right & Fill Down!

---

Using `MS365` Functions --> `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT($A3,," "),
IFERROR(INDEX(x,BYCOL($B$1:$K$1,LAMBDA(m,XMATCH(1,N(x+0=m))))),""))
```

---

And Fill Down, no need to fill right as it spills.

---

Since you are using `Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019` you need to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A3," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),
MATCH(1,N(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A3," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")=B$1),0)),"")
```

---

You can also define a name for the `FILTERXML()` formula

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_VALUE,MATCH(1,N(MAIN_VALUE=B$1),0)),"")
```

---

Where `MAIN_VALUE`

```
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A9," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")
```

---

And you need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> after entering the formula and exiting the edit mode.

---

**EDIT**: Formula found to be working for OP

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(" "&B$1&" "," "&$A3&" "),B$1),"")
```

---

And Fill Down & Fill Right!

---

More simple & succinct alternative as proposed by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B$1," "&$A3&" ")),B$1,"")
```

---

And Fill Down & Fill Right!

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using MS-Office 2019 Professional Plus and the code  is showing nothing. Fully blank.

Comment: I already hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER  but result is same [All blank].

Comment: @riad when you download this workbook, what do you see is it still showing blank, can you confirm once for me: **[Download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ci0dHxfkSfimXodTh?e=8gdVWf)**

Comment: Yes. The provided excel showing perfect answers.

Comment: So that means its working for you right ?

Comment: Just `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B$1," "&$A3&" ")),B$1,"")` would do if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Agreed Sir. Realized that later after posting. updated Sir =)

Answer (score 2):

### Split & Group Data (VBA)

[image]

```vb
Sub SplitData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const DELIMITER As String = " "
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    ' Write the row labels to an array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = rg.Columns(1).Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    Dim rData(): rData = rrg.Value
    
    ' Write the column labels to an array.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Rows(1).Resize(, cCount).Offset(, 1)
    Dim cData(): cData = crg.Value
    
    ' Convert the column labels to strings.
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To cCount
        cData(1, c) = CStr(cData(1, c))
    Next c
    
    ' Reference the values range.
    Dim vrg As Range: Set vrg = rrg.Offset(, 1).Resize(, cCount)
    ' Define the values array.
    Dim vData(): ReDim vData(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Declare For...Next loop variables.
    Dim cIndexes, cIndex, SubStrings() As String, r As Long, rStr As String
    
    ' Loop through the row labels.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        rStr = CStr(rData(r, 1))
        If Len(rStr) > 0 Then
            ' Split the current row label into an array.
            SubStrings = Split(rStr, DELIMITER)
            ' Return the matching column indexes in an array.
            cIndexes = Application.Match(SubStrings, cData, 0)
            ' Write the matching values to the values array.
            For Each cIndex In cIndexes
                'Debug.Print cIndex
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    vData(r, cIndex) = cData(1, cIndex)
                End If
            Next cIndex
        End If
    Next r

    ' Write the values array to the values range.
    vrg.Value = vData

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

- Added `rStr`, i.e. `If Len(rStr) > 0 Then` to account for type-mismatch error occurring when the row label (the value in column `A`) was blank.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
=MAKEARRAY(
    ROWS(A3:A7),
    COLUMNS(B1:K1),
    LAMBDA(κ,λ,
        LET(ζ,0+TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A3:A7,κ)," "),
            INDEX(XLOOKUP(B1:K1,ζ,ζ,""),λ)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If A6 or A7 is empty then #value, be nicer to have blanks.

Comment: @JosWoolley:  I am not sure what wrong i have done. It's only showing #NAME? into all fields where i have put the function. please guide.

Comment: @riad Works fine for me as I pasted it into my sheet with my data to test.

Comment: @SolarMike: I am using MS OFFICE 2019 Professional version. The provided functions are not working there.

Comment: @riad that's something else you should have made clear in the original question - so many versions of excel with missing / extra functions.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

`IF(IFERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2,1),0),B$1`,"")

[image]

Based on the comment:

This works for 10, will let you figure out how to deal with 11, 12 etc

But your example does not have any values exceeding 10 so 10 is assumed to be the highest.
IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND(10,A2,1),0)>0,$B1=1),"",IF(IFERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2,1),0),B$1,""))

[image]

Comment: Why have you not used the original entries as given by the OP? What if you replace your entry in `A2` with, say, `3 5 6 7 10`? Won't that incorrectly return a 1 in `B2`?

Comment: @JosWoolley the OP gave an image and I made the effort to type in boring data just to provide an answer. If the Op had made the effort to provide example data that could be copied and pasted then I might have picked that up.

Comment: It's giving wrong value for 10. When it gets 10 it's showing 1 in B1 Column. How we can solve it ?? Please put 10 into your Main Value and test.

Comment: @riad if you had provided data to work with instead of an image I would ahve trapped that before posting my first version. HOWEVER check the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But it's still shows ERROR. I have check it using column name up to 15.  And there showing lot of ERROR result.                                                      
 Main Data 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
2 4 5 10 11 12  2  4 5     10  12   
2 3 6 7 11 13 1 2 3   6 7    11  13  
1 4 5 15 12 14  2  4 5     10  12  14 15
3 5 6 7 10 1  3  5 6 7   10     
1 7 8 9 11 12               7 8 9   12

Comment: @riad both my versions work, as the images come from the excel sheet I built them in. As for the answer by Jos, I tested that as well and that functions correctly. So I think you need to check what YOU are doing.

Comment: @SolarMike: thanks for your answer. Could you please test using 11 12 13 14 & 15. If 11 Comes after 10 then it's not working. Also, B column value is not coming properly. Requesting to test again at your side.

Comment: @riad if you had given quality data ie up to 15 then we could have tested against that. Will you be extending to 100? or 1000? I will let you evaluate the method I have shown so you can expand your own skills.

Comment: @SolarMike: It could be extent maximum up to 50. I Just write it up to 10 for a example. Requesting to revise the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Less complex formula seems to work for me, in B3:

`=IFERROR(IF(FIND(" "&B$1&" "," "&$A3&" ")>0,B$1),"")`

I could use a clear explanation of solution by Mayukh Bhattachary that worked for riad. Just like to learn the logic of different approaches, thanks.