# Split data to particular column name based on criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split

I am trying to split values to particular column name.

[image: Actual Table]

**Expected result**

[image]

I tried few examples based on this link [How to split Column Value under Particular column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141068/how-to-split-column-value-under-particular-column-name). But I don't know how to convert it for me scenario.

Comment: Don't you need the data to not include the Quarter 3? (`Poor` instead of `PoorQ1`)

Comment: That is also fine

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your inputs and those are very helpful. I learned new formulas in Excel. All you answers provided me the solution but stackoverflow accepts one solution as best answer.

Comment: I think judging by your comments of having 16k rows, JvdV's TEXTAFTER solution may calculate faster (don't know about FILTERXML, but that requires Windows environment to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=DROP(REDUCE("",B1:F1, LAMBDA(a, b, LET(c, TEXTBEFORE(A2:A6,b,,0,,""), HSTACK(a, IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(c,"{",-1,0,,c),""))))), ,1)`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     x,TEXTSPLIT($A2,,"{"),
     IFERROR(INDEX(x,BYCOL($B$1:$F$1,LAMBDA(m,XMATCH("*"&m,x,2)))),""))
```

---

Or, with one single dynamic array formula using <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A6),COLUMNS(B1:F1),LAMBDA(a,b,
  LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A2:A6,a),"{"),INDEX(XLOOKUP("*"&B1:F1,c,c,"",2),b))))
```

---

Or, use variables to avoid repetition,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, A2:A6,
     b, B1:F1,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(b),LAMBDA(x,y,
     LET(z,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(a,x),"{"),TEXTBEFORE(
     INDEX(XLOOKUP("*"&b,z,z,"",2),y),b,,,,"")))))
```

---

Comment: When I try all the formula. I am getting an error #SPILL!. I tried all the solution provided by everyone. What could be the issue?

Comment: The issue could be you might have dragged formula down, which you shouldnt do as the formula will spill, or there could be some other values or formulas for which the formula is not spilling or you may be using `Structured References`

Comment: I tried for more rows but looks like I can do this only for 696 records. After this I am getting #SPILL =MAKEARRAY(ROWS(B2:B696),COLUMNS(C1:P1),LAMBDA(a,b,
  LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(B2:B696,a),"{"),INDEX(XLOOKUP("*"&C1:P1,c,c,"",2),b)))). Is there any row limit for this formula

Comment: @Mangoski try the one without spill. The first approach, which only spills right, not sure why it is happening. However I have just tried for 10K rows of data works fine on my end

Comment: @Mangoski can you show your excel?

Comment: @Mangoski please download to see this excel **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckAoVt9x1UxL-zp4a?e=KJ14o4)** all formulas posted by me, P.b Sir & JvdV sir are all working solution

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTAFTER("{"&LEFT(A2:A6,(FIND(B1:F1&"{",A2:A6&"{")-1)),"{",-1),"")
```

---

And alternatively, using `FILTERXML()`, for fun:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6,"{","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.)-"&LEN(B1:F1)-1&")='"&B1:F1&"']"),"")
```

**Note:** This option would include the 'Q1-Q5' options in the results.

Comment: `FILTERXML()` old is gold =)

Comment: I think I found a much cleaner way now, but `FILTERXML()` was my passion so I couldn't resist =) @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: Ah Cool Sir you always amaze me ! Damn Solution!!!

Comment: I especially love the Textafter/Left/Find construction.
This would also work: `=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6,"{","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.)-"&LEN(B1:F1)-1&")='"&B1:F1&"']"),B1:F1,""),"")` or is there a different way to solve the exclusion of the Q# inside the filterxml?

`=LET(t,IFERROR(TEXTAFTER("{"&LEFT(A2:A6,(FIND(B1:F1&"{",A2:A6&"{")-1)),"{",-1),""),IFERROR(--t,t))` to make the numbers show as numbers.

Comment: @P.b it's hard to exclude the Q and number using `FILTERXML()`. We can offcourse wrap `TEXTBEFORE()` around the solution to get the substring before the last `Q`.

Comment: I am able to perform this for rows only A2:A696. Is there any way I can make this formula work for 'N' of rows?

Comment: @Mangoski all these formulas given works fine, i have tried with `10K` rows of data without any problem it works clinically. How large is your data?

Comment: My data count is 16K

Comment: @Mangoski it still works without any error or fail.

Answer (score 1):

So, for those on earlier versions where lambda(), textbefore(), textafter(), textjoin(), textsplit() etc don't exist:

[image]

Text versions of formulae:

For Q1: IFERROR(MID($B2,1,(FIND(C$1,$B2,1)-1)),"")

For Q2: IFERROR(MID($B2,FIND(D$1,$B2,1)-1,1),"")

For Q3: IFERROR(MID($B2,FIND(E$1,$B2,1)-1,1),"")

For Q4: IFERROR(MID($B2,FIND(F$1,$B2,1)-1,1),"")

For Q5: IF(IFERROR(FIND(G$1,$B4,1),0)>0,MID($B4,FIND("{",$B4,FIND("{",$B4,1)+1)+1,FIND(G$1,$B4,1)-FIND("{",$B4,FIND("{",$B4,1)+1)-1),"")